# States of doctrine entities

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

Suddenly doctrine orm has such a behavior:

`$em = $connection->getEntityManager();
    $entity = $em->find('SomeModel', 1);
    $entity->setName('name');
    $em->flush();`

And it will affect a database because a model have managed state.

`$em->getUnitOfWork()->getEntityState($entity); //1 === UnitOfWork::STATE_MANAGED`

It spoild a lot of nerves for me and now i want to know when can i get entities from a database with managed state?

Comment: sorry, I don't get your question?

Comment: It looks like you already are getting entities with managed state. Are you wanting to get them _without_ managed state?

Comment: thats an case of getting entities in managed state. 
I wan't to know more cases when i can get entities with managed state, because potentially it can make a lot of troubles.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, any entity you get *from the entity manager* will initially be in a managed state. The only time you will need to explicitly manage an entity with `persist()` is if it is created outside the entity manager, like:

```
$entity = new SomeModel;
$em->persist($entity);
```

or created in a different entity manager (in which case it would still be managed, but by the *other* entity manager, so calling `flush` on your entity manager would not affect your database).

If you don't want an entity to be managed, you can [`detach`](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/working-with-objects.html#detaching-entities) it.

```
$em->detach($entity);
```

From [the documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/working-with-objects.html#detaching-entities):

> An entity is detached from an EntityManager and thus no longer managed by invoking the EntityManager#detach($entity) method on it or by cascading the detach operation to it. Changes made to the detached entity, if any (including removal of the entity), will not be synchronized to the database after the entity has been detached.